# Problem with "only assignment, call, etc." while i was trying to make my 2D character not jump in the air

Tags: unity, c#

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class move2d : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float moveSpeed = 5f;
    public bool isGrounded = false;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        Jump();
        Vector3 movement = new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), 0f, 0f);
        transform.position += movement * Time.deltaTime * moveSpeed;
    }

    void Jump()
    {
        if (Input.GetButtonDown ("Jump") && isGrounded == true) {
            gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(new Vector2(0f, 5f), ForceMode2D.Impulse);
        }


    }
}
```

and another file for stopping my character from jumping in the air

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Grounded : MonoBehaviour
{
    GameObject Character1;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        Character1 = gameObject.transform.parent.gameObject;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }

    private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision) {
        if (collision.collider.tag == "Ground")
        {
            Character1.GetComponent<move2d>().isGrounded == true;
        }
    }


    private void OnCollisionExit2D(Collision2D collision) {
        if (collision.collider.tag == "Ground") 
        {
            Character1.GetComponent<move2d>().isGrounded == false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem you're running into? I'm not sure it's clear right now

Comment: Idk exactly but something about move2d not working

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, whenever you get a compiler error, it's vital that you include both the *full* error message:

> Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement

*and* the line that the error occurs on:

```
 Character1.GetComponent<move2d>().isGrounded == true;
```

Second, this type of error is called a syntax error. It's not a problem with your game-specific logic that you need a gamedev expert to solve. It means you got the fundamentals of the language wrong.

Here, it's because you used the equality comparison operator `==` when what you wanted was the assignment operator `=`.

`Character1.GetComponent<move2d>().isGrounded == true;` means "*Is* `move2d.isGrounded` currently true?" - ie. it's a conditional, something that only makes sense inside an expression like the inside of an `if (...)` check.

`Character1.GetComponent<move2d>().isGrounded = true;` means "*Set* `move2d.isGrounded` to be true." - ie. it's an assignment, which is one of the valid kinds of statement in C#.

The error message is saying that you can't use an expression (like "5" or "x + 3" or "Is y true?") on its own line as a statement (like "Make x true").

When you get a basic syntax error like this, you should always search our [general programming sister site StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) first. They have lots of examples of beginners making exactly this mistake, so you can easily find your solution in the existing answers:

- https://stackoverflow.com/q/45704028/3064164
- https://stackoverflow.com/q/50456280/3064164